# Splitting field with Galois group $A_7$

Tags: galois-theory

I'm trying to find a splitting whose Galois group is $A_7$. Nothing else is specified, so I can choose whatever field I want to work with.

One approach I had in mind was to look for an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $7$. But I'm not sure where to begin without just guessing and hoping that I get what I want. We also didn't cover too much about discriminants apart from the definition and their use in analyzing cubics and quartics, so I'm not too confident in this approach in general either.

This problem appears as practice for quals, so I'm assuming there should be a reasonably quick approach to this that doesn't require bashing out discriminants and verifying if they are squares or not.

Comment: Need it be over $\Bbb Q$? There's a standard proof that, for any group $G$, there is some field extension $L/K$ with Galois group $G$

Comment: @FShrike It doesn't have to be over $\mathbb{Q}$. That result you stated definitely sounds familiar, so I'll look over my notes.

Comment: Not sure about this, but maybe try the base field as $\mathbb{Q}(s_1, \ldots, s_7, \sqrt{\Delta})$ where $s_1, \ldots s_7$ are indeterminate variables, $\Delta$ is the discriminant of $x^7 - s_1  x^6 + \cdots - s_7$, and the polynomial is the aforementioned $x^7 - s_1 x^6 + \cdots - s_7$?

Answer (score 1):

We can take the polynomial $f(X)=X^7-56X+48$. It is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$ and has Galois group $A_7$. For a nice proof see the notes by [K. Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/galoisSnAn.pdf), Example $2.7$ on page $4$. So you can take the splitting field of $f$. The key fact is Theorem $2.2$ in the notes.